# ERROR not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)

Tags: json, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I'm trying to make a chat app and want to use SignalR. But when I try to install the Nuget-package I keep getting this error.

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) / win-x86.
```

I tried to find a solution but all the solutions I found claim to modify the dependencies in project.json. I'm using VS2017 and I don't have project.json but I can edit the dependencies in the project.csproj file, which looks like this.

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding" Version="1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
```

Does anybody have any idea how to remove this error so I can use SignalR to make a chat application